# Архивировать только «скрытые» файлы

Tags: linux, tar

```
tar -cvzf archive.tar.gz .*
```

Шаблон **.*** не работает

Как архивировать только файлы/каталоги, имена которых начинаются с точки?

Comment: Закавычьте: `".*"`

Comment: @PinkTux, не работает

Comment: Может... `\.*` ?

Comment: @donRumata, тоже самое ...

Comment: странно, у меня и без кавычек архивировать хомяк начал, строго по маске :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

например так:

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -regex './\..*' | tar -cvzf archive.tar.gz -T -
```

если не устраивает префикс `./` перед именами файлов/каталогов, то чуть длиннее:

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -regex './\..*' -printf '%P\n' | tar -cvzf archive.tar.gz -T -
```

---

можно и без `-regex`:

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name .\* | tar -cvzf archive.tar.gz -T -
$ find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name .\* -printf '%P\n' | tar -cvzf archive.tar.gz -T -
```

---

а можно и без *find*:

```
$ tar -cvzf archive.tar.gz .??*
```

но под маску не подпадут файлы/каталоги с именем, состоящим из двух символов. типа `.1`. тогда так:

```
$ tar -cvzf archive.tar.gz .[^.]*
```

Comment: без find вообще хорошо)

Comment: @ssfn, учтите, что под маску `.??*` не подпадут файлы/каталоги с именем, состоящим из двух символов.